# JavaScript canvas live update

Tags: javascript, canvas, live-update

I wrote a fractal image generator which can run from fractions of seconds to several minutes, depending on the number of iterations for each pixel. In the current version, the user has to wait for the image to become fully rendered until he can see the result. During this time the browser UI is blocked, and Firefox will display a warning message every 10 seconds, asking whether the script should be continued, debugged or stopped.

Question: Is it possible to display updates of the canvas contents while the script is running?

Comment: try using setTimeout when recursively calling your fractal generation function to avoid firefox popping up warning message

Answer (score 1):

Yes

The UI is blocked until the current call (usually started by an event) has returned. When the function returns any changes to the DOM are updated and the next event if there is one is placed on the call stack and called, else the javascript engine just waits for an event.

You can use setTimeout to schedule an event, process some pixels, set the timeout again exit and so on.

Example just in terms of a logic flow

```
var complete = false;
var pixels = 100000;
var pixelsPerCall = 1000;
function addPixels(){
     // process x number of pixels
     var i = pixelsPerCall;
     while(i-- && pixels--){
         // do a pixel
     }
     if(pixels === 0){
          complete = true;
     }
     if(! complete){
         setTimeout(addPixels,0);
     }
}
addPixels();
```

Though for this type of app you are best of using webWorkers. Depending on the number of cores the machine has you can get a huge increase in throughput. Eg an I7 CPU with 8 cores will complete the job ~8 times as quick. Also web workers do not block the DOM so can run for however long you want.

Comment: Thanks for this hint towards the right direction. I tried both window.setTimeout and window.requestAnimationFrame to update the image every second. Both are working, but requestAnimationFrame really updates the canvas frequently every second, while the time setTimeout needs varies between ~0.5 and ~2 s. What are the advantages and disadvantages of these 2 methods?

Comment: For instance, what about backward compatibility? Will every modern browser support requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: @stbi requestAnimationFrame (rAF) lets the DOM/browser know that the code called is related to graphics. It holds any changes made in the offscreen buffers until the display refresh (V-sync) so you do not get flickering / shearing or waste time presenting graphics when it can not be seen. I generally always have a rAF update running to handle all DOM related updates. If there is nothing to do I just request the next frame and exit. And many other reasons. I wouldn't have a clue which browsers dont support it

Comment: After some testing I decided to stick with setTimeout since requestAnimationFrame makes Firefox unresponsive towards user input like button klicks (Chrome and Opera work OK here). The user should be able to stop the image drawing process by clicking on a "Stop" button.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible approaches would be to split your computation into chunks, run each single step with `setTimeout` / `setImmediate`, update the canvas and run another chunk.

This not only updates the canvas incrementally but also stops the browser from complaining about long running script.